# Problem with Constant Current power supply

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, comparator, constant-current, error

I built this schematic recently. The Constant Voltage mode works as a treat, stable as it needs to be. When I insert the LM311 comparator, the circuit works fine for about 30 seconds, then something happens.The comparator switches to pull down the output, however, the positive input has higher voltage on it.It remains in the same state if I short out the input pins to each other. On the OPAmp, the voltage difference on the input pins is really small, but the output is fully on the positive supply level.I can recover the circuit from this state only if I remove the power. I can only think, that the IC-s are not in DC operation anymore, or one or two of them is latching somehow. Sadly, I dont have access to a scope to see what happens, and never had this sort of problem. Can anybody help me what to do with this problem?[image: Schematic]

Comment: Upvote this comment if you hate twisting your neck to read component values on a schematic.

Comment: Sorry for that, not so much room in there.

Comment: @replete just learn to read in all directions.

Comment: Have you checked if any of the ICs gets hot and maybe shuts down normal operation?

Comment: The schematic shows 33V D6 tied to +29.4V and -5V through 10 ohms.  Is this a schematic error?

Comment: "The comparator switches to pull down the output, however, the positive input has higher voltage on it." - what are the actual voltages on + input, - input, output and power supply pins? Have you probed these points with a scope to check for oscillations?

Comment: JohnBirckhead That supposed to be an overvoltage protection for the comparator, it can only handle 36 volts on power pins, while the NE5534 can handle up to 44 volts. 

@BruceAbbott I do not own a scope and do not know anyone who can help me probe around.

Arsenal Yes, they're cold af.

I somehow managed to make this pile of something to almost work. Moved D7 to the opamp output, now it seems like it's not oscillating. But the comp is still latching, maybe R13 is too low.It switches to CC mode with a short circuit and stays there. Second time I ended up with 2 burnt thru 2n3055s.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the problem. Originally, this circuit used a TL081 as a comparator. I changed it to LM311, because why not. This is what caused the trouble. The TL081 has a JFET input stage, while the LM311 has transistors. Transistors are controlled with current, so there is an input current.That is why I have measured voltage on the input tied to ground through a resistor. And that is why the comparator latched. Made some mods to the pcb(it looks like it's done by a one handed blind apprentice), and just threw in a TL071. Now it seems like working, at least the comparator is not latching. But this thing has small issues, but those can be solved by changing a few resistors. Thank you all for trying to help!